# Debuging Excel VSTO differences between Development and Deployment

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2012, vsto

I just finished writing an update to a previous VSTO add-in to 2010-Excel.  It has a ribbon customization including the launching of a windows form.  On my development machine it works just fine and loads the form, but in the deployed version it doesn't work.  It also doesn't throw an exception anywhere that I've been able to catch, and I'm at a loss as to what I could have done that prevents the window from loading.

With out a better idea, I started putting in break points and messages boxes:

```
Private Sub RibbonControlPanelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles RibbonControlPanelButton.Click
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("VSTO_LOGALERTS", 1)
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS", 0)
    MsgBox("1")
    Dim cp1 As New ControlPanel
    MsgBox("2")
    cp1.Show()
    MsgBox("3")
    cp1 = Nothing
    MsgBox("4")
End Sub
```

On this test I made it to "1", so the failing is in making a `New ControlPanel` which is my windows form.  I tried putting a similar series of notes in

```
Private Sub ControlPanel_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

But none of them make it.  Therefore I know that it's not even loading.  How can get more info about what's going wrong?  I can't see any exceptions being recorded anywhere.  My previous version still works (`cp1` is made and shown), but I've tweaked so many things I'd hate to go back to it to rebuild.

I was under the misconception that if it worked on in the development environment, it would work on a nearly identical deployment environment.  Is there a way to make these merge?  I feel like I could debug so much faster if I could interact with the problem in VS2012, but the moment I install VS2012, the thing works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer on this.  While I'm not qualified to officially call this a MS bug, it seems that way.

It kept failing to make the new instance of the Win. Form, but I wasn't getting any kind of error when I was trying to launch it from the Ribbon.  I changed the start-up conditions for `this workbook`, so that it tried to make a new instance of the Win Form then.

That's when I got an error that PowerPacks 10 could not be found.  Which seemed strange, because on my Clickonce deployment, PowerPacks 10 was listed as a prerequisite.  It was further confused by the fact that had previously installed the "public" version of powerpacks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb735936.aspx), which is version 3.  Somehow that passed the check of the installer, but wasn't what was needed by the program.  When I DL the version from the [link in the installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=145727&clcid=0x804), which is in fact version 10, everything worked.

I've double checked and found that v10 is listed as prereq, but for some reason, it wasn't getting caught by the Clickonce installer.  I think the reason that my previous versions of the program worked but the current version didn't, was a use of different kinds of lines in my forms (of all the reasons!).

Hope this can save someone else the heart ache.